# Location aware Silverlight webpart

Tags: web-part, silverlight

We are designing a system where we will have a site per customer. The site will be created based on a custom site template.

This site will have a Silverlight webpart, that will get data from a Line-of-Business application via a web service.

Is there a way in which the Silverlight application can know which site it is on, so that it requests the correct data?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`ClientContext.Current`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.client.clientcontext.current.aspx)

http://blah.winsmarts.com/2009-12-ClientContextCurrent_is_null_in_Silverlight.aspx

Answer (score 3):

If you are using the client object model you should be able to say `ClientContext.Current.Web` to get the current site.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee538971.aspx